# Application alive in background forever - private app

Tags: objective-c, background, ios9, ios10

This is for a private application which is able to do some stuffs when the application is connected to a BT selected by the user. 
We use the `bluetoothmanager.framework` via https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee unfortunatly it doesn't seems to be able to awake the application if it's in background.
*Possible ? We would be glad to have any clue how to do it with*.

So we need to find a way to keep the app alive in background while the user didn't kill it whithout an huge battery consumption.

Currently we use this work around which keep the app. alive between 2 & 4hours max. (not enough obviously, but with this one the application consume nothing : ~1% in 2 hours)

**Background mode :**

- voIp
- Location update
- background fetch
- audio play

**code used :**

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"account"]){

            _background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {
                NSLog(@"cleanup code for end of background allowed running time");
                [application endBackgroundTask: _background_task];
                _background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }];

            // run background loop in a separate process
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                NSLog(@"start of background loop");
                while (TRUE)
                {
                    NSTimeInterval remaining = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining];
                    // background audio resets remaining time
                    if (remaining < 60) {

                        [self playSpeech:@"up" andVolume:0.0];
                    }
                    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]; //wait for 1 sec
                }
                NSLog(@"end of background loop");
                [application endBackgroundTask: _background_task];
                _background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            });

            [[Detector singleton] startDetection];
        }
    }
```

Any clues about how Keep the application in background alive without ruining the battery of the user ?

Comment: *Keep the application in background alive without ruining the battery of the user* ? that's contradiction. If the background task does not do anything, it won't cost battery life. But if you use GPS / Bluetooth, it must consume battery constantly (though BLE reduces the use of battery a lot)

Comment: I'm not allowed to be to specific, but currently there's some conditions to do "some stuffs" after being connected to the BT. So the current work around in a normal use is about ~1%/2h of battery consumption, but since the OS force to sleep the app after a moment, this solution isn't viable

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Bluetooth 4 and BTLE, then one solution would be to register (as you mentionned) for background location updates.

With the help of CoreLocation, you can setup [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager) to monitor up to 20 different Regions. Regions can obviously be made of geographical/GPS areas, but also made of an iBeacon area, it's called a [CLBeaconRegion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeaconRegion_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLBeaconRegion).

Thus, if you implement this design, your app could be awaken when entering and/or exiting a CLBeaconRegion. Best of all, if your app was killed after registering for a region monitoring, iOS will wake it up once the boundary is crossed.

**Swift 2 example:**

```
// setup your CLLocationManager :

var locManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
locManager.delegate = self
locManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

// Register for region monitoring : 

let uuid: NSUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: "BF89DEDF-35E1-93A2-D316-2381E10A28EF")!
let majorValue: CLBeaconMajorValue = CLBeaconMajorValue(UInt16(63468))
let minorValue: CLBeaconMinorValue = CLBeaconMajorValue(UInt16(13575))
let beaconRegion: CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: majorValue, minor: minorValue, identifier: "my-beacon")
self.locManager.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)

// from there implement the CLLocationManagerDelegates to get updates while in forground :

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)
{
    print("locationManager didEnterRegion = \(region)")
    if let beaconRegion = region as? CLBeaconRegion
    { 
        // do your stuff
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion)
{
    print("locationManager didExitRegion = \(region)")
    if let beaconRegion = region as? CLBeaconRegion
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}

// and to know if iOS woke you up when your app was asleep or terminated, you need to check the presence of the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey in your AppDelegate :

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil 
    {
        // here you know you've been woken up about region crossing... 
        // you need to restart your region monitoring as explained in the documentation*, and do your stuff... 
    }
}
```

*[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey doc here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationlaunchoptionslocationkey?language=objc)

This is quite a simplified code, besides all this you need to handle several things like the user aknowledgment to keep location always in background, etc... But that's one way to go.